# How to find the original MIME type of a file while uploading it?

Tags: java, security, spring-security, mime-types, multipart

I have to find the original content type(MIME Type) of a file at the time of Uploading.

I want to allow only PDF files, But if i am renaming an .exe fiel to .pdf flie, its type is showing pdf.

I want to restrict these kind of files.

**I am using the following code:**

```
if (!fileMultipart.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("application/pdf")) {
        msg = "Only pdf files are allowed.";
        System.out.println("Only pdf files are allowed.");
    }
```

Also some online tools are available to find the original content type. I tried using http://www.checkfiletype.com/ and it works.

Comment: You can't do anything easy. The problem is not on your side, if the server from which you download type the file as pdf, then you cannot do anything more smart. You may try to verify that there is the PDF header in the file itself but I'm not sure it will worth the effort, or?

Answer (score 0):

The file content type is determined by the user-agent/browser on upload. As you already know, this can be spoofed, or incorrect. There really isn't more you can do with just the file's content type.

An alternative is to do more checking after you have verified the content type by attempting to open the PDF for reading using [iText](http://itextpdf.com/), [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/), or some similar library. If you can't open the file then you can let the user know there's a problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isPDF(String fileName) {

  File file = new File(fileName);
  System.out.println("file upload isExist " + file.exists());
  boolean result = false;
  //Scanner input = null;
  try {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
     System.out.println("fileScanner input " + input);
     while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        final String checkline = input.nextLine();
        if (checkline.contains("%PDF-")) {
           // a match!
           result = true;
           break;
        }
     }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
     System.out.println("file upload is not valid " + file);
     Logger.getLogger(UploadContractorFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
  System.out.println("file upload final result " + result);
  return result;
 }
```

Comment: I have instance of MultipartFile not File, and I do not have path of file as I am checking it at the time of Uploading. I do not want  to save file in temporary loaction.